# "Translating" between two different definitions of neighborhood?

Tags: general-topology

I am working on a basic point-set topology problem: Prove that in a locally-connected space $X$, the quasi-components of $X$ are open.

I know of one way to do this, which relies on the following definition of $neighborhood$:

A $neighborhood$ of a point $x$ is an open set $U$ containing $x$.

Since locally-connected spaces have a neighborhood basis of connected sets, and since components are contained in quasi-components, we can find an open (connected) set around each point contained in the quasi-component, showing it is open.

On the other hand, this definition is presenting a problem:

A $neighborhood$ of a point $x$ is a set $V$ which contains an open set $U$ containing $x$.

Now the proof of this result doesn't seem so obvious to me. I'm sure it's true using this definition of neighborhood, but I'm not sure how to go about proving it. I'm having a similar difficulty with other problems and the two different accepted definitions of neighborhood.

My question: Is there a way to more or less "translate" between these two definitions of neighborhood, making proof techniques that work for one work for the other, and vice-versa?

If not, could someone give me a push in the right direction on solving my quasi-component problem with this second definition of neighborhood?

Comment: Well an open set $U$ contains itself, vice versa given a second-definition neighborhood $V$ it contains $U$, work on that $U$. It's all local.

Comment: The problem with this is that local-connectedness guarantees connected neighborhoods, not connected open neighborhoods. There is also no guarantee that an open subset of a connected neirhborhood is connected.

Comment: Take the connected component of that open subset in which $x$ lies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can set the difference between two concepts of a neighborhood aside by observing that the following holds for **either** definition:

> A set is open if and only if it contains a neighborhood of each of its points.

Take a quasicomponent  $A$ and a point of it. It has a connected neighborhood $U$. The definition of quasicomponent implies $U\subset A$. Thus, $A$  is open.